# `DynamicObject` on right hand side of binary operation

Tags: c#, dynamic-language-runtime

I am trying to make my dynamic class behave as `System.Int32` in arithmetic expressions. However, I seem to be unable to handle situation when a dynamic instance is being added to an integer:

```cs
dynamic i = new MyInt();
// the following line throws
// Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
// "Operator '+' cannot be applied
// to operands of type 'int' and 'MyInt'":
int result = 1 + i;
```

```cs
class MyInt: DynamicObject {
    public override bool TryConvert(
                            ConvertBinder binder,
                            out object? result) {
        if (binder.Type == typeof(int)) {
            result = 42;
            return true;
        }
        result = default;
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TryBinaryOperation(
                            BinaryOperationBinder binder,
                            object arg, out object? result) {
        if (binder.Operation == ExpressionType.Add) {
            result = 42 + (int)arg;
            return true;
        }
        result = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I do not want to define `operator +` accepting the first argument of type `System.Int32` on `MyInt` because `MyInt` is not actually necessarily an integer type - that is determined at runtime, so defining it on the class would be misleading for people using static typing. Is there any other way?

Comment: `int result = i + 1;` should work, right? According to the MS docs `object arg` should be the right-hand side argument of the operation

Comment: @JHBonarius it does, but I am developing a library, and the users would expect the operation to work either way, because that's how it would behave with static typing.